# Bigquery - How to Calculate the sum of two continuous rows

Tags: google-bigquery

How can I get the sum of two rows clubbed together for instance If I have 5 rows in total, I should get 3 rows a result.

Below is my table:

```
2020-08-01 1
2020-08-02 3
2020-08-03 4
2020-08-04 2
2020-08-05 4
```

I want to achive this:

```
4
6
4
```

```
August 1 and 2 = 4
August 3 and 4 = 6
August 5 = 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT dt, val, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dt) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT SUM(val)
FROM cte
GROUP BY FLOOR((rn - 1) / 2)
GROUP BY MIN(dt);
```

Here is a demo link, shown in SQL Server, but whose logic should also be working for BigQuery:

### Demo

Comment: thanks for fast response.
Not working in bigquery @Tim.
Giving the same 5 rows with value.
i.e.
1
3
4
2
4

Comment: @ShivamChauhan I suspected this might happen.  Try aggregating by the floor of the expression I am using above.  This should get around the problem in Big Query.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for Bigquery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT SUM(value) AS value, 
  STRING_AGG(FORMAT_DATE('%B %d', day), ' and ') || ' = ' || CAST(SUM(value) AS STRING) AS calc
FROM (
  SELECT day, value, DIV(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY day) - 1, 2) grp
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t
)
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY grp
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2020-08-01' day, 1 value UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-08-02', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-08-03', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-08-04', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-08-05', 4 
)
SELECT SUM(value) AS value, 
  STRING_AGG(FORMAT_DATE('%B %d', day), ' and ') || ' = ' || CAST(SUM(value) AS STRING) AS calc
FROM (
  SELECT day, value, DIV(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY day) - 1, 2) grp
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t
)
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY grp
```

with output

```
Row value   calc     
1   4       August 01 and August 02 = 4  
2   6       August 03 and August 04 = 6  
3   4       August 05 = 4
```